# See if timestamp is more than 24 hours in a JSP site

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm making a JSP site where I'm struggling a bit
I'm using bash to ping an IP - and setting a timestamp for the last change 
This is set by Bash as:

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

How can I check weather this timestamp is set less than 24 hours or not. 
The meaning if the VPN is disconected less than 24 hours ago - it'll marked  yellow text.

Comment: "less than 24 hours" and "less than 24 hours ago" is not the same. not sure what you are actually looking for, but I doubt you'll ever find a timestamp which indicates 'more than 24 hours' since that is the limit of hours in a day. a timestamp is one single moment in time, not a duration

Comment: I have a timestamp written inside MYSQL - created with Bash as date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S   -  When getting it inside my JSP page - its a String.  
I want to know if this inserted timestamp is more or less than 24hours old

Comment: so, parse it to a date, and compare it to the system date

Comment: You will need to know which time zone your `bash` uses.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Since you tagged your question java, I assume you want to do this in Java within your JSP.

```
    ZoneId bashZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String timestampString = "2018-11-08 00:07:22";
    ZonedDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, formatter)
            .atZone(bashZone);
    if (timestamp.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now(bashZone).minusHours(24))) {
        System.out.println(timestampString + " is more than 24 hours ago");
    } else {
        System.out.println(timestampString + " is *not* more than 24 hours ago");
    }
```

When I ran the code just now, the output was:

> 2018-11-08 00:07:22 is *not* more than 24 hours ago

Please substitute the time zone that your bash uses if it didn’t happen to be Europe/Copenhagen. You may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you trust your JVM time zone setting to coincide. It doesn’t always, and furthermore may be changed at any time even from another program running in the same JVM, so is fragile.

java.time is the modern Java date and time API that since 2014 has replaced the old date-time classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and others. The old classes were poorly designed, so I recommend you use the modern ones.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse that String timestamp to `LocalDateTime`.
You can use LocalDateTime methods to check if your date is older than 24 hours.

```
String str = "2018-01-20 11:32:53";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
return date.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.